# Java reactor to return different exception

Tags: java, error-handling, project-reactor

I have this client which its call is:

```
return client
            .post()
            .uri(SERVICE_ENDPOINT)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .syncBody(request)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(CustomResponse.class)
            .map(CustomResponse::getAck)
            .doOnNext(this::validateResponse)
            .doOnError(throwable -> doOnError(throwable))
            ;

private void ValidateResponse (String ack) {
      if ("ERROR".equals(ack)) {
           throw Exceptions.propagate(new BadResponseException(ack));
      }
}

private void doOnError(Throwable t){
    if(throwable instanceof ReadTimeoutException) {
        throw Exceptions.propagate(new CustomReadTimeoutException(throwable));
    } 
    throw Exceptions.propagate(new CustomInternalException(throwable));
}
```

The problem is that even when I have BadResponseException, it goes to the onError and then the error is of type CustomInternalException.
How do I keep the error type to be stayed BadResponseException?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that the `Throwable t` passed as argument to the invocation of `doOnError(Throwable)` is of type `CustomInternalException`? If `onError` refers to _some other method invoked as a result of the exception thrown from_ `doOnError`, then it seems logical that the the resulting exception in `onError` is of type `CustomInternalException` as you wrap the `Throwable` passed to `doOnError(Throwable)` in a new `CustomInternalExcetpion`.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken the Throwable could be of type BadResponseException and I would like that on the doOnError it will be propagate to the user. and not the general exception of type CustomInternalException

Comment: Then isn't this merely a matter of _not_ wrapping the `Throwable t` in `doOnError(Throwable)`, i.e., just rethrow `t` if `t instanceof BadResponseException`?. Disclaimer: I do not know what framework etc. you are working.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `doOn*` methods are not meant to change the signals from the original sequence, but more for usage like logging ("side effects").

Although throwing from these methods is correctly caught and transformed to an `onError` signal downstream, I would recommend adhering to stricter standards and replace:

- the `doOnNext` with a `map`, simply rewriting the `ValidateResponse` to return the original `String` when not throwing.
- the `doOnError` with an `errorMap(Predicate<Throwable>, Function<Throwable,Throwable>)`

Any `Throwable` will go through the `doOnError`, which default to wrapping the exceptions and throwing the wrapped one.  By having a predicate in an `errorMap`, you'd wrap only specific exceptions and avoid your issue.